# mysql select query with join not showing the results of multiple rows from the same table

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I am trying to create a search form for my database where a user can search for a customer name and all of that customers addresses will be displayed. my structure looks like this

Customer table

- ID
- First Name
- Last name
- Company Name

Address Table

- ID
- line 1
- post code
- town
- Customer_ID

Site Table

- ID
- Address_ID
- notes

I take either the first, last, or company name as an input and store this as a variable along with which column they want to search in then  I use the following query to check the database for matching criteria

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.Customer_ID INNER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID WHERE upper(customer.$field) LIKE'%$query%'") ;/
```

I print the results using

```
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
            echo "<br>"; 
            echo $results['First_Name']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['Surname']; 
            echo $results['town']; 
            echo " "; 
            echo $results['postcode'];
```

The problem occurs when one customer has multiple addresses. A home address and a site address that are different. The query will only print one of the addresses, the site address ( which is submitted second and seems to overwrite the home address)

in the address table both of these addresses contain the same Customer_ID, how can I get them to both be displayed rather than just one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your search query to find the customers but then come back and get all the records for that particular customer. Doing so as a subquery should do the trick:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.Customer_ID 
INNER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID 
WHERE Customer.ID IN (SELECT ID 
                      FROM customer 
                      INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.Customer_ID 
                      INNER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID 
                      WHERE upper(customer.$field) LIKE'%$query%')
```

Comment: I still get the same problem when using this

Comment: @dan Can you include some sample data in your question then? I believe this should work the way you are describing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use LEFT OUTER JOIN when you connect SITES. If you use INNER JOIN you lose ADDRESS records whose Id's are not in sites.address_id.